# HTML Dom injection with HTML/Template within a script tag

Tags: javascript, html, go, templates, go-templates

I ran into this error in attempting to build some javascript using the html/template package. The compiler seems to be confused about the context and state of what I am doing. Is there any way to override the compiler here and avoid this message? Below is a sample of the code I am trying to execute.

> The template failed: html/template:javascript.partial.tmpl:18:10: on range loop re-entry: {{range}} branches end in different contexts: {stateJSRegexp delimNone urlPartNone jsCtxRegexp attrNone elementScript }, {stateJS delimNone urlPartNone jsCtxRegexp attrNone elementScript }

```
function addParameter(){
        let div = document.createElement('div');
        div.id = 'parameter'+parameterIndex.toString();
        div.innerHTML = `<input type="text" name="parameters_value">
                <select name="parameters_key">`+
                {{range $index, $value := .User.Keys}}`<option value="{{$value.KeyHTML}}">{{$value.KeyPlain}}</option>`+
{{end}}
                </select>
                `
```

I found the issue covered similarly on google groups in 2012, but the answer is for package text/template and so a solution from this source is unclear. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/8L4eDkr5Q84

It seems like if I could assert state to the compiler as being stateHTML instead of stateJS then it wouldn't have this problem. Is this something I am able to do?

Comment: Is the template an HTML template, or javascript? If you're dealing with a javascript file, you can use tex/template instead of html/template.

Comment: It's part of a broader pipeline of template parsing and execution, and this piece needs to fit as a {{template}} call into an HTML page. Is it possible to mix text/template parsing and execute as html/template with the rest of my pages?

Comment: Update: I came up with a workaround by initializing the data into a javascript []string array, then building the javascript snippets individually. Would be great to know the solution here though if there is one for future reference.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the  content within a <script> tag?

Comment: The code was only a portion of the total snippet. A <script> tag immediately followed the {{define}} template tag. Thanks for the idea, though!

Answer (score 2):

This could work as intended, but the backtick in Javascript is used to define [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). I believe the [`html/template`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/) package is not well equipped to handle those.

So an easy fix is not to use template literals but simple string literals in JavaScript, so you may use template actions and you can still have context-sensitive escaping.

Use this template:

```
<script>
function addParameter(){
        let div = document.createElement('div');
        div.id = 'parameter'+parameterIndex.toString();
        div.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="parameters_value">'+
                '<select name="parameters_key">'+
                '{{range .User.Keys}}<option value="{{.KeyHTML}}">{{.KeyPlain}}</option>{{end}}'+
                '</select>';
        document.body.appendChild(div);
}
var parameterIndex = 1;
addParameter();
</script>`
```

Testing it with input parameters:

```
t := template.Must(template.New("").Parse(src))

type Key struct {
    KeyHTML, KeyPlain string
}
m := map[string]interface{}{
    "User": map[string]interface{}{
        "Keys": []Key{
            {"h1<", "p1<"},
            {"h2>", "p2>"},
        },
    },
}

if err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, m); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

This will output the following HTML:

```
<script>
function addParameter(){
        let div = document.createElement('div');
        div.id = 'parameter'+parameterIndex.toString();
        div.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="parameters_value">'+
                '<select name="parameters_key">'+
                '<option value="h1\x3c">p1\x3c</option><option value="h2\x3e">p2\x3e</option>'+
                '</select>';
        document.body.appendChild(div);
}
var parameterIndex = 1;
addParameter();
</script>
```

Which if you open in a browser, properly renders the HTML, even the escaped `"h1<"`, `"p1<"` values appear correctly.